# What is wrong with £ symbol when using it in encryptor?

Tags: dart

When I use £ symbol in password according with an AES encryptor I get the error

> Key length must be 128/192/256 bits

```
String pass = 'my_cool_password_£..............';
var key = Key.fromUtf8(pass);
var encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv); // error `Key length must be 128/192/256 bits`
```

Stack trace
Unhandled exception:

```
Invalid argument(s): Key length must be 128/192/256 bits
#0      AESFastEngine.init (package:pointycastle/block/aes_fast.dart:66:7)
#1      SICStreamCipher.init (package:pointycastle/stream/sic.dart:55:22)
#2      StreamCipherAsBlockCipher.init (package:pointycastle/adapters/stream_cipher_as_block_cipher.dart:27:18)
#3      PaddedBlockCipherImpl.init (package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart:43:12)
#4      AES.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/aes.dart:19:9)
#5      Encrypter.encryptBytes (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:12:19)
#6      Encrypter.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:20:12)
```

the package was used https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt

here is the package `encrypt` function

```
Encrypted encrypt(String input, {IV iv}) {
    return encryptBytes(convert.utf8.encode(input), iv: iv);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using UTF-8 to represent your password, you need to take into account that not all letters can be represented with only 1 byte (8 bits).

E.g. the `£` is represented by using two bytes (16 bits): `c2 a3`

This can be seen in the following example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(utf8.encode('my_cool_password_£..............').length * 8); // 264
  print(utf8.encode('my_cool_password_x..............').length * 8); // 256
  print(utf8.encode('£').length * 8); // 16
  print(utf8.encode('£').map((i) => i.toRadixString(16))); // (c2, a3)
}
```

Comment: how did you found that the £ char is defined as: c2a3 ?

Comment: You can either use a table like: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/ or get it from dart with: `print(utf8.encode('£').map((i) => i.toRadixString(16)));`